# How to encode with ffmpeg PCM to AAC with different sample formats?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav, libavformat

I'm using the following code to encode PCM to AAC using libav. It works with sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16; and a newer release of liabv. In older versions, only sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT is allowed, but then the decoder always returns 0 (nothing decoded). **What in the code do I need to adapt in order to make it work with sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16? Is sample_fmt the input or output format?**

```
 avcodec_register_all();
 codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_AAC);
 c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

 c->bit_rate   = 64000;
 c->sample_rate= 44100;
 c->channels   = 1;
 c->frame_size = 86000;
 c->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT;//---> this works with AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16

buf = (uint8_t *)malloc(bufSize);
audioData = (uint8_t *)malloc(size);

//fill audioData

int packetSize = avcodec_encode_audio(c, buf, bufSize, 
         (short *)audioData);//------>returns 0 when using AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT
```